# Computing the matrix derivative of $W^T T W$ w.r.t. W

Tags: matrix-calculus, orthogonal-matrices

I am trying to analytically and numerically compute the derivative of the following function

$$
J(W) = \frac{1}{2}\|W^T R W - I\|_F^2
$$

From a paper that I am reading, the derivative of this function

$$
Q(W) = \frac{1}{2}\|W^T W - I\|_F^2
$$

w.r.t to W is

$$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial W} = W(W^TW-I)
$$

(Which is wrong, by the way, because there should be a constant 2 that multiplies everything).
Going back to my problem, according to my calculations,

$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial W} = R^TW(W^TW-I)
$$

(of course, also in this case there should be a 2 multiplying the whole expression).

To compare the goodness of these derivatives, I am using a software to compute symbolic derivatives. I am using W with random values. Computing $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial W}$ with the analytical expression above and the software for symbolic differentiation, I get (almost) the same results (elementwise differences are approx $10^{-15}$).

With the $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial W}$, I instead obtain two different results between my analytical expression and the software that computes the derivatives for me.

To convince myself, I am treating the gradient matrix as an image and I plot the results here: [Analytical vs Theano](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnDVM.png)

As you can see, visually the results seem correct, but elementwise the results diverge a lot. For example, I took the item at location [50,50] and this is what I get

- Analytical expression: 1290.2355448
- Theano symbolic deriv: 1213.77161213

I dont't understand whether:

1. I am wrong (and please, help me to fix the expression of my derivatives)
2. Theano is computing something different (?)
3. It is only a problem of numerical approximation (probably, but unlikely, since the first case with the same data gives exactly the same matrices)

Thanks to anyone that can give me any support

Comment: I forgot to mention that W and R are square matrices

Comment: Concerning your computational differences on the order of $10^{-15}$. This is nothing more than computation error. Computers can only work with fixed number of bits, so they cannot represent every real number, but only a finite set of them. When you multiply or divide two of these numbers, the result is not their true multiplication or division, but rather the nearest number in that finite set to the true value. This error builds up with repeated calculations, so you have to expect bigger errors in the results of complex calculations. You can safely consider those calculations as being equal.

Comment: That I know it and the only way to check whether two matrix are "equal" is to see if their error is less than an epsilon. In fact, the first derivative which error is ~10e-15 is fine. I am concerning about the other derivatives, which error is 15 order of magnitudes higher and I do not understand where is my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Define a new matrix variable $$A=W^TRW-I$$ 
Then write the function in terms of the inner/Frobenius product 
(denoted by a colon) and this new variable. In this form, the differential and gradient
are simple to calculate
$$\eqalign{
 J &= \frac{1}{2}A:A \cr
\cr
dJ &= A:dA \cr&=A:(dW^TRW+W^TR\,dW) \cr
   &= AW^TR^T:dW^T + R^TWA:dW \cr
   &= (RWA^T+R^TWA):dW \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial J}{\partial W} &= RWA^T+R^TWA \cr
   &= RW(W^TRW-I)^T + R^TW(W^TRW-I) \cr
\cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your differentiation works perfectly

Comment: How did you know that $W$ as symmetric ? If that is not the case then $dW \neq dW^{\top}$

Comment: Nowhere do I assume that $W$ is symmetric. Instead I make use of the following property of the Frobenius product $$B^T:dW^T = B:dW$$ to rearrange some of the terms.